# get returned data to display inside of vue model

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple set of data that will come in from my method. I need the data to display inside of my vue model thats all which is inside an object or array. Honestly, any that works. Normally, just adding vm.array name or object name works on success but cannot get it to display.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mydata:{}
  },
  methods: {
    getTokenData(){
            $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
   
            success: function (data, status) {

                alert("success");
                console.log(data);
                this.mydata=data;
              
  },
  mounted: function(){
   this.getTokenData();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{mydata}}
 
 </div>
```

Comment: I've never used a non cli made vue project, try using this.getTokenData() in mounted. Maybe try adding a console log to the method to see if it's running properly. I also haven't ever used the ajax method your using, but imagine an ajax call it returns a promise so it could be that.

Comment: Yes data returns in console. Just trying to get it in model

Comment: I have a feeling the context of "this.mydata=data" inside the function is getting it's "this" context messed up. Can you check the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work well

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
       mydata: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTokenData(){
           
           axios
            .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            .then((response) => {
               
                // this.mydata=data;
                if (response.status) {
                  this.mydata = response.data;
                   console.log("myData ===>", this.mydata);
                }
            });
     }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.getTokenData();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   title: {{mydata.title}}
   <br>
   body: {{mydata.body}}

 </div>
```

Comment: vote me if you are satisfied. thanks :)